# Reducing Size / Compressing JSON String in C++

Tags: c++, json, compression

Is there a way to compress a JSON string in c++ , so that the overall size can be reduced ?

In my case mobile app which retreives XML create by CCUserDefault, then it converts that XML to JSON using rapidJson. Now I want to reduce its size or compress it using any cpp library.

Comment: You could gzip the response to the client (assuming it is being sent down to the browser). You could also strip unneeded whitespace.

Comment: C++ alone does not have any compressors. you can use zlib.

Comment: Micheal, I am sending JSON string to server from mobile app.

Comment: if the strings are larger, you might want to simply compress them: i.e. [snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/)

Comment: you could also switch to protocol buffers or msgpack if you have the option

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to minimise the size of the string (as opposed to general compression such as gzip), then a library such as [`rapidjson`](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/) could be used.

There's an example in [this unit test](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/source/browse/trunk/test/unittest/writertest.cpp?r=64):

Roughly:

```
StringStream s("{ \"hello\" : \"world\" ");
StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
Reader reader;
reader.Parse<0>(s, writer);
EXPECT_STREQ("{\"hello\":\"world\"}", buffer.GetString());
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am already getting the JSON string from rapidJSON which I further want to compress

Comment: In that case I'd change your question to focus not on JSON, but on network compression. Are you sending the package over HTTP? If so you're probably looking for an HTTP client that supports GZIP.

Comment: Yes I am seding it over HTTP. Yes HTTP client that compresses JSON string using c++

Answer (score 0):

You could use zlib to compress the JSON string in memory and decompress it back. Perhaps using the ideas in [here](https://panthema.net/2007/0328-ZLibString.html)